# Conditional probability for two normal distributed variables.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I haven't had to do much with probabilities since university, so please excuse if this is trivial or the question is not well specified.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent, normally distributed random variables with means $\mu_x $ and $\mu_y$, respectively and standard deviations $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = 1$. Having observed one "draw" of $X$ and $Y$ ($x_1$, $y_1$) with $x_1 > y_1$, what is the probability that $\mu_x > \mu_y$?

In case the following question is easier to answer, an answer to it is even preferred:

Under the observation that $x_1 - y_1 = \delta$ , what is the probability that $\mu_x > \mu_y$ (as a formula of $\delta$)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: yes, they are independent. I will add this to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have thought that unless you want to get tangled in the language of one-tailed hypothesis tests, a Bayesian approach might be best.

But even then you would need a prior distribution for $\mu_x-\mu_y$; let's suppose there is an improper prior where this difference (call it $D$) is uniformly distributed. Then given $D$, the likelihood of observing $\delta$ is proportional to $\phi\left(\frac{\delta-D}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ and so the posterior density for $D$ is $\dfrac{\phi\left(\frac{\delta-D}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\int \phi\left(\frac{\delta-D}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dD} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \phi\left(\frac{\delta-D}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.

So taking this prior, the posterior probability that $D \gt 0$ given $\delta$, i.e. the posterior probability that $\mu_x \gt \mu_y$ is $$\Phi\left(\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is based upon the assumption that $D$ is uniformly distributed. Doesn't a uniform distribution always need to have an upper and lower bound specified? Are these bounds irrelevant to your answer?

Comment: A prior uniform distribution over the reals is [improper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Improper_priors). If that makes you uncomfortable, consider the result as the limit when the upper and lower bounds of a bounded uniform distribution are extended towards $\pm \infty$